# Prove that a determinant of a matrix is different than $1$

Tags: determinant, upper-lower-bounds

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\zeta_{p}$ be the pth roots of unity and let $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension and $G=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})$ be its Galois group we know that $|G|=\phi(p)=p-1.$

And let $S=\{1,\zeta,\zeta^{2},.....,\zeta^{p-2}\}$ be a basis of the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ and let $m_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha x $ be a linear operator, and $[m_{\alpha}]$ be its matrix representation.

Let $\alpha=1+\zeta +\zeta^{2}+....+\zeta^{m}. $

And $\det[m_{\alpha}]$ be its determinant. I want to show  that $|\det[m_{\alpha}]| \neq 1$ for some value of $m>c$ where $c$  is a number. In other words, is there any good lower bound which helps as to show that $|\det[m_{\alpha}]| \neq 1$ ?

Comment: I guess you want to exclude $p=2$.

Comment: @Severin Schraven I don't what is the value which makes the determinant bigger than  1 .can say why you said this?

Comment: Because it looks like it is not true for $p=2$. The second (primitive) root of unity is $\zeta=-1$, but then we get $\alpha=0$ (for $m$ odd) or $\alpha=1$ (for $m$ even), none of which will yield a determinant bigger than $1$.

Comment: Ah sorry, misread, thought you wanted bigger than $1$. If you want it just different from $1$, then you can just note that $\alpha=0$ for $m=p-1$.

Comment: @Severin Schraven can you prove that for $p>2 $$detDet[m_{\alpha}] \neq 1$? Or you it just an observation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\beta=1-\zeta$, we have
$$[m_\beta]=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\-1&1&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&-1&1&\cdots&0&1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&1&1\\0&0&0&\cdots&-1&2\end{pmatrix} =:A_{p-1}$$
and by developing along the top row, say, we find $$\det A_n=\det A_{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}\det(-I_{n-1})=\det A_{n-1}+1$$
and with $\det A_1=2$ ultimately $$\det [m_\beta]=p.$$
The determinant of a linear map does not depend on the choice of basis. Therefore, we more generally have $\det [m_{1-\xi}]=p$ for any primitive $p$th root $\xi\in\Bbb Q(\zeta)$, in particular for $\xi=\zeta^{m+1}$ with $p\nmid m+1$.
As $\alpha=\frac{1-\zeta^{m+1}}{1-\zeta}$, we conclude that
$$ \det [m_\alpha]=\frac{\det [m_{1-\zeta^{m+1}}]}{\det[m_\beta]}=1$$
for all $m\not\equiv -1\pmod p$.
On the other hand, for $m\equiv -1\pmod p$, we clearly have $\alpha=0$ and so $\det [m_\alpha]=0$.

Comment: so i understand that $Det[m_{\alpha}] \neq 1$ when  $ m \equiv $ $1 mod $ $p $ ? Can make the last part more clear

Comment: also i  didn't say  that $\alpha = 0$ also    $\alpha$     is fixed as above